# Check if Textfile.txt Contain Certain Strings

Tags: string, vb.net, forms, if-statement, contain

I am creating a system to validate if a text file contains this serial number, if it contains it opens to Form2.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim content = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(filePath)
If content.Contains(stringToSearch) Then
    Dim form As New Form2
    form.Show()
End If
```